# Devise: Overriding the sessions#new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

**I want to be able to send already-signed-in-users somewhere else when they go to the sign in page**. Right now they are sent to the root path.

I tried making my own new action in sessions controller but it doesn't seem to work. The text I try to print out on the log to test out doesn't even come out, so I think the user is redirected somewhere up the chain.

How do you do this?

Comment: How about a `before_filter` in which you check `params[:controller] == "devise/sessions" && params[:action] == "new"`

Comment: That could work. I could put that in the application controller, and send redirect them somewhere if `user_signed_in?`. I'll try it.

Comment: If there's another way I'd like to find out though. Because this would mean for every request I'd be firing this before filter.

Comment: You could restrict when the filter "fires" by using the `:only` option. If you're worried about performance, then checking a simple condition in a before_filter is unlikely to degrade your app's performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [after_sign_in_path_for](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#after_sign_in_path_for-instance_method). If you define that method in your application_controller.rb file you can return whatever path you want the user to be redirected to.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if current_user.current_sign_in_at > 1.minute.ago
    your_own_path
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmm.. no it's not that. That's where you send after a successful sessions#create. I want to redirect them somewhere else besides the root path if they are logged in **and** they try to go to the login page.

Comment: From my testing I think that after_sign_in_path_for is also called when a logged in user revisits the login page. If you need to send them two different places you try checking the users `current_sign_in_time`. See the updated example above.

Comment: Thanks, I see why I got confused. The first `if` in `after_sign_in_path_for` is `resource_or_scope.is_a?(User) && can?(:manage, current_site)` - and that, I imagined, would return true if the user has already signed in and they go to the `sign_in` page. But it didn't, so I created another elsif block with this: `user_signed_in? && can?(:manage, current_site)`.